Unwanted second label with european resistor in circuitikz
When I'm trying to use a european resistor with a label in my RLC circuit it places an unwanted second label at (0,0). I'm quite new to circuitikz so this might be an easy fix, but i can't find a solution.
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,3)
    to [short] ++(1,0)
    to [R=$R$, european resistor] ++(2,0)
    to [short] ++(1,0)
    to [capacitor, l_=$C$, capacitors/thickness=3] ++(0,-3)
    to [cute inductor, l_=$L$, mirror] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



The syntax of
to [R=$R$, european resistor] ++(2,0)

is wrong(*). If you want a (local) European resistor the syntax is
to [european resistor=$R$] ++(2,0)

But the idea is that you choose a style and use it for all of your circuits, so I suggest:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{european resistors}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) to [short] ++(0,3)
    to [short] ++(1,0)
    to [R=$R$] ++(2,0)
    to [short] ++(1,0)
    to [capacitor, l_=$C$, capacitors/thickness=3] ++(0,-3)
    to [cute inductor, l_=$L$, mirror] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


And by the way, to [R=$R$, european resistors] ++(2,0) (notice the final s on resistors) would have worked because while european resistor is the name of the component, european resistors is a style.
If instead, you usually want American (zig-zag) resistors, and this is a "just here" change, you can choose between the solution at the top or using:
to [generic=$R$] ++(2,0) 

Notice also that the "set the style" can be extended to the other choices you have, and that an unadorned (without labels, or currents/voltages/flow) short is the same as a line, you can rewrite your circuit like this:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{european resistors, cute inductors,
   capacitors/thickness=3}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,3) to [R=$R$] ++(4,0)
    to [C, l_=$C$] ++(0,-3)
    to [L, l_=$L$, mirror] ++(-4,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}

(Same output --- but now you can change your mind and change all your circuits to, say, american inductors and american resistors just editing one place...)

(*) technically, you are putting two bipoles (european resistor and R) in the same to command, calling the path-stroking routine twice, the second one with no setup --- this is why you have the stray R around.
